# Too Many Indices error, using recurrent neural network for natural language generation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a project based on the code from this article:  https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/build-a-natural-language-generation-nlg-system-using-pytorch/

I am getting an error when trying to train the model as shown:

```
# train the model
train(net, batch_size = 32, epochs=1, print_every=256)
```

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-7c9ee6264cba> in <module>
      1 # train the model
----> 2 train(net, batch_size = 32, epochs=1, print_every=256)

<ipython-input-66-6d3226f72734> in train(net, epochs, batch_size, lr, clip, print_every)
     17 
     18         # x_int, y_int, list of numbers that each represent a vocab word
---> 19         for x, y in get_batches(x_int, y_int, batch_size):
     20             counter+= 1
     21 

<ipython-input-63-4e36dace452e> in get_batches(arr_x, arr_y, batch_size)
      7     for n in range(batch_size, arr_x.shape[0], batch_size):
      8      #taking row from prv to n and all columns
----> 9       x = arr_x[prv:n,:]
     10       y = arr_y[prv:n,:]
     11       prv = n

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Which then points back to an issue setting up the arrays on line 9 (x = arr_x[prv:n,:]) of this part of the code:

```
def get_batches(arr_x, arr_y, batch_size):
         
    # iterate through the arrays
    prv = 0
    #Range returns a sequence of numbers
    #yield returns a batch each loop (using yield keeps local variables)
    for n in range(batch_size, arr_x.shape[0], batch_size):
     #taking row from prv to n and all columns
      x = arr_x[prv:n,:]
      y = arr_y[prv:n,:]
      prv = n
      yield x, y
```

I am not sure on what I need to change/how to set up the array for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like arr_x is 1 dimensional array. But you are trying to address it like 2-dimensional

Comment: Thanks for the response! That is what I was thinking as well, but I am not sure how to/what I need to change in order for it to be a 2-d array. I am very new to NLG and RNN but have been searching around for quite a bit on how to fix this.

Comment: There are a lot of ways (`tf.reshape()`, `tf.stack()`, etc.) depending on what you want to do

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since it is a numpy array is tried to do np.reshape() and wasn't able to get that to work either, although I may not be using the correct values inside the parenthesis.